# How to detect windows OS in shell script

Tags: bash, operating-systems, shell-script

I would like to write a cross-platform script using shell so I can run it on linux, mac os and windows. I'm using cygwin on windows to make this possible. However, there are some custom commands that I need to execute on windows only. Is there a way to detect if the shell if running on windows in shell script? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the output of the `uname` command to determine the underlying OS.

Comment: Thanks! I also found OSType is available for my purpose.

Comment: Note that this won't work with Microsoft's _Bash on Windows_ feature in Windows 10. `uname` reports `Linux`.

Answer (score 1):

Found a brilliant solution at https://nastytester.com/posts/script-that-works-in-windows-and-linux.html

Essentially, you're creating a bash function that will at the same time leverage the goto command from Windows CMD.

```
    echo off
    
    goto(){
    # Linux code here
    uname -o
    }
    
    goto $@
    exit
    
    :(){
    rem Windows script here
    echo %OS%
    exit
```

If you require the passing of arguments, you can use my version here:

```
    echo off
    
    goto(){
    # Linux code here
    echo -n 'Found OS Type: '
    uname -o
    sleep 5
    if [[ -z "$@" ]]; then
      echo "No argument was detected. Project argument is required."
      sleep 5
      exit
    else
      ./linux_launch.sh $@
    fi 
    }
    
    goto $@
    echo "End of Linux function."
    exit
    
    :(){
    rem Windows script here
    echo.Found OS Type: 
    echo %OS%
    set ARG=%1
    echo %ARG%
    if [%ARG%]==[] goto NOARG
    timeout /t 5
    start /wait cmd.exe /c ".\master_launch_1.bat %ARG%"
    goto EOF
    :NOARG
    echo.No argument was detected. Project argument is required.
    :EOF
    echo.End of Windows function.
    timeout /t 5
```